# If $x \in A$ why does it not follow that $x \in A-B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that if $x \in A-B$ then $x \in A$ because $x \notin B$ but why doesn't the reverse hold true?

Comment: Suppose $A = \{2, 3\}, B = \{1, 2, 3\}.$  Then there is no $x \in A$ that is in $A-B$.  Similarly, if $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B= \{1, 2\},$ we can't conclude that just because $x\in A$ that $x \in A-B$,

Comment: Because $A - B \subseteq A$ always, but we can't generally say that $A \subseteq A - B$.

Comment: So if $A$={1,2,3} and $B$={1,2} then there would be $x \in A$ that's in $A-B$ namely {3}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $A\setminus B$ only includes elements in $A$ *which are not also in $B$*. Put differently, $A$ can be partitioned as
$$
A = (A\setminus B )\cup (A\cap B)
$$
and if $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ but $x\notin A\setminus B$.

For instance, take $A=B=\{1\}$ for a trivial counterexample. Then $A\setminus B = \emptyset$: so $1\in A$, but $1\notin A\setminus B$.